# What is the reason for the error "Device supports x86, but APK only supports armeabi-v7a"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am playing around with Android Studio by testing some projects out from GitHub and when I try to emulate the apk, it does not let me choose an emulator.

It tells me:

> Device supports x86, but APK only supports armeabi-v7a

Why does it do this?

Comment: What AVD did you use? What System Image? What GitHub project?

Comment: In other words, the Intel x86 images aren't going to run ARM code.

Comment: https://github.com/jreyes/mirror

Comment: I wanted to use a Nexus 10 running android 5.1

Comment: Okay, and did you use the ARM eabi v7 system image or an Intel Atom x86 image? Check your SDK manager what you have installed.

Comment: feel very stupid. Just had to go to the "Other Images" tabs to find arm devices. Thank you!

Comment: For me I had to re-enable usb debugging for some reason..

Comment: These happens to me periodically on Pixel XL 2.  If i unplug usb c cable and plug it in upside down it fixes it sometimes.  Other times I have to reboot the phone.

Comment: Hey! I got the same error playing with Vulkan samples under MS WIndows 10 and the last Android Studio. Any clue how to fix this error?

Comment: @AlexanderIbarra It's not that you are stupid. It is that Android Studio has hundreds of settings and doesn't give many clues even for very common things like this.

Comment: Same issue with pixel2 emulator for many android projects.

Answer (score 107):

I had the same problem, I checkout the *build.gradle* from *module:app*. It turns out that there's a such config:

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
```

when I commented all out, everything worked fine.

**I was trying to deal with the React Native Android project**.

Comment: I think you meant build.gradle ;)

Comment: I had the same problem and for me "x86" was just missing there

Comment: This worked for me - however all I had to do was allow debug on my actual device and I could uncomment this line again.

Comment: Which section should I put ndk?

Comment: Didn't work for me in java/kotlin, it builds but app crashes.

Answer (score 80):

Turn off USB debugging and turn it back on the hardware device.

Comment: Those comments I would normally downvote, but actually, it works!

Comment: This works because the `Allow computer to connect to this device` prompt didn't display the first time, but did the second time.

Comment: This worked on a computer I had "remember for this computer" marked on when I started a new project from GitHub.

Comment: So. After adding new processors architecture to ABI filter - studio stopped recognizing device.  This tip helped me to resolve the issue.!!

Comment: For me this is happening in Emulator

Answer (score 49):

In Android Studio, select the **Build** menu,

[image]

then click **Select Build Variant...** and in 'Build Variants' window select **x86Debug**(or release)

[image]

PS: Im using Android Studio 2.3 on Mac

Comment: This worked perfectly - my gradle setup defined both ARM and x86 builds, but I had to instruct Android Studio to build the x86 variant as opposed to the ARM variant (likely for iOS). Thanks!

Comment: Note that you need to have the project selected, or the option to do this will be greyed out. I think there are some other conditions that can grey it out too - you may need to Make Clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 16):

On Linux:
File > Invalidate Cache / Restart 
On phone: 
Instead Charge this device change to Transfer photos (PTP)

Comment: None of the above answers were working. This worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I changed from `Camera (PTP)` to `Media Device (MTP)` and it works too. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I had the similar issue and I've resolved it by adding "x86" value to the "abiFilters" list like below -

*[Open build.gradle(Module: app) file ]* 
and search for "**ndk**" in **deafultSection** and add "x86" to it!

```
ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: You should probably drop `armeabi` if you're targeting SDK 19 and above. Android itself doesn't support it starting 4.4

Comment: @mradzinski can you provide a link to the documentation about support as well?

Answer (score 12):

The code below worked for me:

```
ndk {
     abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case of Linux machine `adb devices` showed

```
List of devices attached 
44b194f5    no permissions
```

Then restarted the adb server

```
sudo adb kill-server
```

and then

```
sudo adb start-server
```

then connect your device turn Debugging on and type

```
adb devices
List of devices attached 
44b194f5    device
```

Finally was able to run on the device

Answer (score 8):

In my case my app use some native libraries. Each platform requires the corresponding libs to be built.

So the  native lib of x86(or any other) platform is not generated.You must have add an abifilter somewhere:

There are several places where abi filters can be specified:

- Application.mk
  add the platform you need like this:

  ```
  APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
  ```
- build.gradle

  find abiFilters, and add platform you need like this:

  ```
  abiFilters   "armeabi","armeabi-v7a","x86"
  ```

Answer (score 8):

You need to **reconnect** your device and try to **turn off/on** the developer options.

See [Enable developer options and debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options)

Answer (score 6):

> Device supports x86, but APK only supports armeabi-v7a)

Sounds like you used an `x86` image in the emulator.

Create a separate one. Choose "other images" tab to find arm devices, if you have to.

Or, run on an actual device. The repo you listed is meant to run on a Raspberry Pi 3 / ODroid, I think.

Answer (score 6):

Can confirm, toggling USB debugging off/on in Developer Options resolved the issue. Maybe even cancel the "Select Deployment Target" window in Android Studio and try to run the app again after toggling USB debugging.

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked my changing the cable option from

```
-> Charge Only.
```

To

```
-> Transfer file.
```

Answer (score 4):

Just go to device `Settings >> Developer Options >> Restore Default Settings` then enable `USB debugging`

Answer (score 2):

On my physical device, I started getting this.  The fix was to go into Developer Settings and turn off and on USB debugging.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Ubuntu:

1. make sure that usb debugging is ON
2. check your cable connection
3. on notification bar check android system notification and touch it for change charging state to file transfer
4. now go terminal and type:
   adb devices
   after run this command adb restart and your device show in list

Answer (score 1):

adb kill-server

adb start-server

Its working for me on windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Test your code on real phone. If you have still same issue,then import your code again and before this you should update your SDK and create a new emulator with ARM system image.

Answer (score 0):

Many times this means that you have not granted your laptop/computer access to your device. Take a look at your device and click the "Allow Access" button as well as the debugging permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Running an AVD using the x86 processor is 10x faster than using the ARM emulator, but most of the time you are only compiling your APK for ARM. To have faster emulation runs using an x86 AVD I had to do the following (for a Cocos2d-x project):

- app/jni/Android.mk

  ```
  APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a:x86
  ```
- gradle.properties

  ```
  PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:x86
  ```
- app/build.gradle

  ```
  android {
      ...
      defaultConfig {
          ...
          ndk {
              abiFilters = []
              abiFilters.addAll(PROP_APP_ABI.split(':').collect{it as String})
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting device solved problem for me (React-native)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me to after updating the Android Studio. In my case, it happened because of the build setting is not automatically configured into x86Debug-x86.
Just change it by opening Build>>Select Build Variant>> Change the build variant option from armeabi-v7a into x86Debug-x86 or whatever you need in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling **Unknown Sources** from Security Options.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i see this

If you’re using CMake for your builds, then check the file \proj.android\gradle.properties, and update the PROP_APP_ABI to include the builds for x86, or alternatively, you could just use the armeabi-v7a or arm64-v8a Android images.

Example:
PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:arm64-v8a:x86

If you’re not using cmake, then look in \proj.android\app\jni\Application.mk in case you need to change the ABI setting in there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's problem ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

ndk {
abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
}

Answer (score 0):

This issue got in my emulators. I have created new and the issue persists.

I am using studio in Mac. I did not shutdown/restart my machine since a week. May be memory issue of the emulators while booting. I don't know but gave a try to shutdown and open studio and then no warnings. Build is successful.

Note: This may not be the solution but worked for me.