# Device Supports <Undefined> , but APK only supports x86

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to deploy and debug an app for different CPU ABis via my Android Emulator but get this error.

[image: It's not saying what it supports]

It doesn't specify what ABI the Emulator supports. I've tried running an APK that supports all ABIs but still get the same error.

This only happens to Emulators with a Google Play System Image. I have no issues deploying to the clean x86 System Image which isn't Google Play or Google APIs.

I'm running on Windows 10 64-bit, and on HAXM 6.1.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need better fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the Emulator Image, I downloaded and update and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775988/what-is-the-reason-for-the-error-device-supports-x86-but-apk-only-supports-arm).

In `build.gradle`, check this block

```
ndk {
    // abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
}
```

you either add what your device support or comment `abiFilter` out.

Comment: This can be used as a temporary solution, since the filter is not just installed here, probably

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a Motorola G6 Plus plugged in via USB. The device had USB debugging already enabled. Toggling USB debugging to off, and then back on again did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Ubuntu:
 1. make sure that usb debugging is ON
 2. check your cabel connection
 3. on notification bar check android system notification and touch it for change **charging state** to **file transfer**
 4. now go terminal and type:
    **adb devices**
after run this command adb restart and your device show in list

Comment: I tried killing adb from terminal using adb kill-server, now its working fine.