# Solving missing run configuration in Android Studio for cloned Kotlin app

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build, adb

I have Android Studio 3.4 and have **cloned a github respository** of a Kotlin-based app ([Voice](https://github.com/PaulWoitaschek/Voice)).  The subject of this question probably would find equivalence in other repositories as well.

The cloning, done from Android Studio, recognizes the Gradle build information in the repository and when prompted, I took the defaults associated with loading the project into the IDE.

> You have checked out an Android Studio project file:
>   C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\VoiceC\build.gradle.kts
>   Would you like to open it?

Group modules: 
`using qualified names`
`Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)`

Gradle home:
`%AndroidStudioLocation%/gradle/gradle-3.2`

Project format:
`.idea`

I get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.

Typically, after the build completes, in *other projects* I've cloned, I am able to click on `Run Selected Configuration` and the APK is loaded to my device using adb.  But in this case, after the build, there are no `Run/Debug Configurations`.

#### Android App Template

I have created a run configuration using `Run` > `Run...` > `Edit Configurations` and then used the `Android App` template, but when I try to run that, I see this in the adb `Select Deployment Target` window:

> (Device supports , but APK only supports armeabi-v7a, x86_64, arm64-v8a,x86)

Since I am able to load other APK's to the device, I thought the basic configuration on the device must already be correct, it's just this project in Android Studio that seems to be the problem.

But using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402946/897007), which has me turning the USB debugging on the device off, and then on again, I was able to get the device to show normally:

> Motorola Moto G (5) Plus (Android 8.1.0, API 27)

Another clue led me to the *Build Variant*, but the menu item `Build` > `Select Build Variant` is not enabled, so I was unable to do anything there.

#### Kotlin Templattes

I have also tried to configure `Kotlin` and `Kotlin script` run configurations, but it's unclear how to configure those in order to get them to do what, in past experience, "just works" (i.e. the run configuration is somehow already defined in the project without my having to do any configuration).

#### Question:

How can I get this application running on my device using an Android Studio run configuration?

> - IDE Details:
>
> Android Studio 3.4
>   Build #AI-183.5429.30.34.5452501, built on April 9, 2019
>   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>   Windows 7 6.1

#### Edit - Additional Information:

Since the build completes successfully, I am able to run, from the command line with the current directory set to the location of the *.apk file:

`C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe install app-opensource-debug.apk`

The problem with this approach is that the application must be manually removed from the device before this will work.  This means any configuration of the app is lost.  It also takes longer since it doesn't take advantage of the ability of the IDE's to run the subset of build steps (for repeated builds with small changes between them - whatever that feature is called).  For these reasons, it would be more convenient to get a working run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

### Android App Template with app:assembleDebug

In the Android Studio project, select `Run` > `Edit Configurations...`

Hit the `+` and select `Android App`.

This will give you a configuration named **Unnamed**.  You can overtype that name with something more descriptive, like **app**.

Near the bottom of the dialog there's a `Before launch...` section.  The default entry there is `Gradle-aware Make`.  Double-click that item.  That will bring up `Select Gradle Task`.

Type `app:assembleDebug`

[image: Android Studio GUI image of building a run configuration]

Now you should be able to `Run` > `Run 'app'` select your deployment target and the project should build, and the application should run on your selected device.

Comment: I don't have any options in Module, so I get an error Module not specified.