# Get working Android Vulkan samples under MS Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, vulkan

I want to test Android Vulkan samples under Android Studio in MS WIndows 10
using this manual https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/getting-started

I cannot do it because of the error

> Device supports x86, but APK only supports armeabi-v7a

I have tried all options suggested here [What is the reason for the error "Device supports x86, but APK only supports armeabi-v7a"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775988/what-is-the-reason-for-the-error-device-supports-x86-but-apk-only-supports-arm/49183583)  but it does not work.

I have following Virtual Devices

[image]

[image]

Even if I use  armeabi-v7a I cannot start app. And it is EXTREMLY slow.

Please help me to use clear steps to get working Vulkan samples under x86 images of Android. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: "*I just need manual to get working Vulkan samples under x86_64.*" The current answer on this question says that this isn't possible, that Vulkan doesn't work through the emulator. Why do you doubt this?

Comment: @NicolBolas Dude, the your answer says it. It explains it in 2 words without dirty water. Create your answer with details and you will gain +50. Thanks!

Comment: But since that's what Jesse Hall already posted, I'd just be repeating it. So why have the bounty at all, just to get an answer you already have? Also, what details can there be beyond "I don't think the Android emulator emulates a Vulkan-capable GPU yet"?

Comment: @NicolBolas Your ethics is spectacular, bro! Let's do it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple different problems here:

First, the "device supports x86_64, x86, but APK only supports armeabi-v7a" means exactly what it sounds like: you've got an emulator that only supports 32-bit and 64-bit x86 instruction sets, but the native code in your APK is only compiled for 32-bit ARM. Emulating x86 devices is much faster since they can run in a virtual machine (the host CPU is actually executing emulator instructions directly, instead of having to translate them one by one in software). Configure your project to build native code for x86 in addition to armeabi-v7a.

Second, when using an ARM emulator, or if you fix the first problem and run on an x86 emulator, I don't think the Android emulator emulates a Vulkan-capable GPU yet. So you should be able to create a Vulkan instance, but `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` should return a count of zero available physical devices.

You don't give any details about "cannot start app": do you see anything in the log? Are you able to create an instance? Or is there some other completely unrelated problem before you even get to that point? Nobody can help you with that without more details.

Comment: Well, I canot even start app. I see the "Select deployment target" popup and the red error at bottom "Device supports x86, but APK only supports armeabi-v7a".

Comment: Yes, that's the first problem I mentioned. Either build your app with x86 versions of the binaries, or run it on an armeabi-v7a emulator target. Then you'll run into the second problem, which is where we'll need more details (like log messages).

Comment: Hi! Well I will not use armeabi-v7a emulator target under MS Windows because it works slowly. Would you mind to suggest how to build app with x86 versions of the binaries for Vulcan samples, please?

Comment: The same way you'd build an x86 version of any other Android app.  See this guide as a starting point:  https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis FYI, you should note that you're better off targeting x86_64 and running an x86_64 emulator than trying to build in 32 bit architecture, especially since all Vulkan handles are 64 bits in size.

Comment: Thanks man! But would you mind to suggest concrete steps to get working Vulkan samples under x86_64? Like 1,2,3, please... (Check my updated question)

Comment: We've given you pointers to adding a x86 or x86_64 ABI to your project, and you reference another question that also describes it. Without knowing what you've done or what results you're seeing, it's hard to give you anything more useful. BUT also see the second problem I mentioned: there is no way currently to run Vulkan samples on the Android emulator. The emulator doesn't have a Vulkan driver.