# Problems running app on OnePlus 7 locally over USB ("Device supports , but APK only supports armeabi-v7a, x86_64, arm64-v8a, x86")

Tags: android, android-studio, abi, oneplus7

I'd like to connect a brand new [OnePlus 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnePlus_7) test device with USB to my dev laptop and install our app to it, straight from Android Studio.

However, Android Studio shows this:

[image]

...and trying to run the app on the device fails with:

> The app doesn't support SDK version of the device: (1).

I found out that this is related to `abiFilters` which we have specified for (both) build types:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
}
```

That is in there for a reason, but I'm new to this and probably couldn't explain it well... Trying to remove `abiFilters` would cause build (`:app:packageDebugBundle`) to fail with "All modules with native libraries must support the same set of ABIs ..."

**Edit**: this boils down to the fact that one module in the app uses a proprietary library including native libraries (.so) that are only available for `[ARM64_V8A, ARMEABI_V7A, X86, X86_64]`. It's beyond our control to change that.

So which ABI is missing on that list? What ABI does OnePlus 7 use? It has a Qualcomm Snapdragon 855 CPU but I couldn't easily figure out what that maps to.

One additional point: **the app works just fine on OnePlus 7 when distributed over Google Play.** Any workaround to make it work also locally?

---

Any other ideas to make this work? The device obviously has USB debugging enabled; could there be some other developer option I'm missing?

Comment: analyse apk and find .so file found? i think this is your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather weird altogether, but got it solved.

I also tried `adb install` on the command line, and it failed with `error: device unauthorized`. That prompted me to try what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546300/56285) suggested: **revoking USB authorizations**.

After that, and re-connecting the cable & giving the USB debugging permission again, clicking "play" in Android Studio installed & started the app just fine on the OnePlus device.

Comment: So the same surprising solution as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49183583/56285