# Change Android Studio Arctic Fox Target to x86

Tags: android, android-studio-arctic-fox

I am volunteering as a mentor for a First Tech Challenge robotics team. I am a professional developer experienced with Visual Studio and other tools but I've never used Android Studio before. I need to target an x86 Oreo device.

When I try to run my project, Android Studio gives me a warning stating "Device supports x86, but APK only supports armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a on device Android Accelerated x86 Oreo".

How can I fix this? The Android Studio documentation is vague and seems to be written for a previous version. This appears to be a simple problem but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason for the error "Device supports x86, but APK only supports armeabi-v7a"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775988/what-is-the-reason-for-the-error-device-supports-x86-but-apk-only-supports-arm)

Comment: I saw that question. The gradle file for my project has no such setting, nor do any other gradle files contain an ndk element. I didn't know if the answer applied or if the target is set somewhere else in Arctic Fox.

As it turns out, the provider documentation was out-of-date. (See below.)

Answer (score 0):

My question is irrelevant. No changes are needed to the project. The documentation for First Tech Challenge is out-of-date. In previous years, the robot required an android phone physically attached to the control hub. Currently, the control hub includes a built-in Android device, so the actual target is the control hub.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).